# In mongodb, how to remove all documents that miss a certain fields

Tags: mongodb

```
db.getCollection('db').find({img:{$exists:false}})
```

is great at finding the documents I want to delete. But

```
db.getCollection('db').remove({img:{$exists:false}})
```

does not delete them:
Removed 0 record(s) in 70ms
Why ? how can i achieve this ?

Comment: For the complete sotry, i'm using robomongo on an mlab db

Answer (score -1):

Don't use robomongo for that ... just the mongo client

Comment: Althought it looks like a comment, that realy was the solution.